# Snowflake updating duplicate records

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am having staging tables in a snowflake where I am copying data from AWS S3 using snowpipe. Some of those records are a type of creating an event and multiple updates. For same event, there will be one create and multiple update events with chronological order. I wanted to move those records in another table (so create event should insert a record into a table and multiple updates event should update those records accordingly.)I was trying to use the "Merge" concept snowflake, but it does not suit well for my use case as if my target table does not have a record, it creates a new record for every creates and updates.

Comment: This question needs a lot of clarification.  Perhaps create an example of your table structures, your data, and what your expected outcome is.  This will help others understand the issue better and provide possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The following SQL will work if any update is a complete new version of the original event and can completely replace the previous, so that you really only have to apply the last update of many.

It is considerably harder if you have to apply all the updates to an event in sequence to get a correct result.  You do not present any details, so that leaves us guessing.

```
MERGE INTO event_tab old USING (
   SELECT * FROM new_events
   QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY event_ts DESC) = 1
) new ON old.event_id = new.event_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ...
```